# Cannot change theme or syntax colors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm running Eclipse Oxygen, newly installed. I also installed CFEclipse, and little else. My syntax is not coloring the way the settings say it should.

- When I go into the Preferences and try to change the syntax colors, nothing gets changed.
- When I right-click and try to change the theme from the context menu, nothing changes. When I go into the Preferences and change the theme there, it recolors but incorrectly, and I get an error.

In the log, it's a long Java error that starts like this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2018-03-02 14:20:37.519
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.AnnotationPainter.setAnnotationTypeColor(AnnotationPainter.java:1090)
at org.cfeclipse.cfml.editors.decoration.DecorationSupport.handlePreferenceStoreChanged(DecorationSupport.java:592)
at org.cfeclipse.cfml.editors.decoration.DecorationSupport$1.propertyChange(DecorationSupport.java:303)
```

Is there something else I need to install?

Comment: Looks like a bug in cfeclipse

Comment: It doesn't seem relevant for your error, but did you also install MXUnit? The install instructions state "_As of November 2017 this additional step is required, owing to the MXUnit domain having expired_" (See https://github.com/cfeclipse/cfeclipse/wiki/Installing-CFEclipse)

Comment: @skomisa, Yes, I did install it. I installed CFEclipse from the dev site, which I believe automatically installs MXUnit. Either way, it says, "All items are installed." Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: OK. Could you update your post to be more precise on exactly what you do in Preferences "to change the syntax colors"? Also, does the date/time in that stack trace correspond to the action in your first bullet point or the second (or neither of them)?